# Сколько подстрок в строке имеют равное количество 3х букв

Tags: python, алгоритм, строки, подстрока

Дана строка, состоящая только из букв A, B и C. Необходимо посчитать за O(n), сколько подстрок содержат одинаковое количество всех трех букв.

Например:

CCAABB - 1(CCAABB),

CBACBA - 5(CBA,BAC,ACB,CBA,CCAABB),

AAABBC - 0,

CCBCCCABB - 1(CAB),

CBACBACBA - 12

Есть попытка решить таким образом, но это решение работает только для некоторых случаев. Подскажите, как решить нормально?
Рекомендовано использовать сеты или словари, но это не обязательно

```
def count(s):
  n = len(s)
  result = 0
  count = {}
    
  for i in range(n):
    print(s[i])
    if s[i] not in count:
      count[s[i]] = 1
    else:
      count[s[i]] += 1
    print(count)

    if len(count) == 3 and count["A"] == count["B"] == count["C"]:
      result += (i+1)/3
      
    elif len(count) == 3:
      if abs(count["C"]-count["B"]==1) or abs(count["C"]-count["A"]==1):
        result += i//3
  
  return result
```

Comment: а это вообще возможно посчитать за O(n)? За квадрат я бы еще понял, но за линейное время есть у меня сомнения.

Comment: @Zhihar предположу просто что это что то из динамическго программироания, по другому у меня даже идей нет ес честно )

Comment: @tym32167 ну задание сформулировано именно так. Я обязательно потом запощу решение преподавателя, когда дедлайн наступит

Comment: @tym32167, у меня пока получается n*(1 + 1/2 + 1/3 + 1/4 + 1/5 + ...) - хотя ряд вроде как расходится, но очень медленно и можно условно для конечного числа n считать, что зависимость линейная kn

Comment: А задание точно так звучит? За линейное время она не решается. Подозреваю, что условия могут быть немного другими.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Линейный.  Составной ключ `diff` соответствует текущему соотношению счетчиков A к B  и  А к С

Ключ - **относительное** соотношение счётчиков для каждого из символов. Например, `(-1,2)` означает, что до текущей позиции количество `B` на 1 меньше, чем `A`, а `С` - на 2 больше, чем `A`. Если это соотношение совпадает для каких-то позиций, то между ними - одинаковое количество всех символов. Например, указанный ключ будет для `BACACCC` и `BACACCCCACABB`, значит суффикс `CACABB` содержит поровну всех символов. Такой же ключ будет для `BACACCCCACABBBCA`, но на этот момент его счётчик уже равен двум, так что есть два суффикса, кончающихся в данной позиции, и содержащие поровну символов.

https://ideone.com/MOIMqj

```
from collections import Counter
def count(s):
    dic = Counter()
    diff = (0,0)
    dic[diff] += 1
    result = 0
    for c in s:
        if c == 'A':
            diff = (diff[0]-1,diff[1]-1)
        elif c == 'B':
            diff = (diff[0]+1,diff[1])
        else:
            diff = (diff[0],diff[1]+1)
        result += dic[diff]
        dic[diff] += 1
    return result


print(count('CBACBACBA'))
```

Comment: Вроде работает, но как именно, я не понимаю.

Comment: @Qwertiy Ключ - **относительное** соотношение счётчиков для каждого из символов. Например, `(-1,2)` означает, что до текущей позиции B на 1 меньше, чем A, а С - на 2 больше, чем A. Если это соотношение совпадает для каких-то позиций, то между ними одинаковое количество всех символов. Например, указанный ключ будет для BACACCC и BACACCCCACABB, значит конец CACABB содержит поровну всех

Comment: А, понял, красиво!

Comment: Все принялось, браво, спасибо огромное!

Answer (score 1):

Вот решение в лоб:

```
text = "CBACBA"

count = 0

for size in range(1, len(text) // 3 + 1):
    for pos in range(0, len(text) + 1 - 3 * size):
        count_a = 0
        count_b = 0
        count_c = 0

        for index in range(3 * size):
            if text[pos + index] == 'A':
                count_a += 1

            if text[pos + index] == 'B':
                count_b += 1

            if text[pos + index] == 'C':
                count_c += 1

        if (count_a == count_b == count_c):
            count = count + 1

print(count)
```

Правда я бы не назвал бы это O(n), скорее O(n(n - 1) / 6) ну т.е. O(n^2) :)

Измененный алгоритм для честных n^2 (плавающее окно):

```
text = "CBACBA"

count = 0

for step in range(1, len(text) // 3 + 1):
    count_a = 0
    count_b = 0
    count_c = 0

    size = step * 3

    for pos in range(size):
        if text[pos] == 'A':
            count_a = count_a + 1

        if text[pos] == 'B':
            count_b = count_b + 1

        if text[pos] == 'C':
            count_c = count_c + 1

    if (count_a == count_b == count_c):
        count = count + 1

    for pos in range(1, len(text) + 1 - size):
        if text[pos - 1] == 'A':
            count_a = count_a - 1

        if text[pos - 1] == 'B':
            count_b = count_b - 1

        if text[pos - 1] == 'C':
            count_c = count_c - 1

        if text[pos + size - 1] == 'A':
            count_a = count_a + 1

        if text[pos + size - 1] == 'B':
            count_b = count_b + 1

        if text[pos + size - 1] == 'C':
            count_c = count_c + 1

        if (count_a == count_b == count_c):
            count = count + 1

print(count)
```

По совету **@Danis** включил словари для уменьшения кода:

```
text = "CBACBA"

total_count = 0

for step in range(1, len(text) // 3 + 1):
    local_count = {"A": 0, "B": 0, "C": 0}

    size = step * 3

    for pos in range(size):
        local_count[text[pos]] += 1

    if (local_count['A'] == local_count['B'] == local_count['C']):
        total_count += 1

    for pos in range(1, len(text) + 1 - size):
        local_count[text[pos - 1]] -= 1
        local_count[text[pos + size - 1]] += 1

        if (local_count['A'] == local_count['B'] == local_count['C']):
            total_count += 1

print(total_count)
```

Comment: Это не квадрат, а куб.

Comment: куб можно свести к квадрату, если использовать скользящее окно. Но вот линейным это уже не назовешь ну никак.

Comment: @tym32167, @Qwertiy - ну да, просто не стал заморачиваться оптимизацией на тему - `-1 +1` при сдвиге на `1`, так что считаем квадратом

Comment: @Zhihar слишком много времени занимает, когда вводишь очень длинную строку. Система не принимает, увы.

Comment: @braflovsky, еще чуть-чуть и победим :) я пока в свой комментарий выложил обновленный алгоритм с плавающим окном - так что это теперь честные O(n^2), а не O(n^3), думаю дальше, пока этот попробуйте - может тесту хватит :)

Comment: @Zhihar может лучше сделать через словарь `counts = {"A": 0, "B": 0, "C": 0}`?

Comment: @Zhihar спасибо) Еще была рекомендация использовать словари или сеты, но это не обязательно

Comment: @Danis, да, можно, но на сложность алгоритма это никак не повлияет, только на читабельность кода, так что пока можно откинуть :)

Comment: по совету @Denis добавил использование словарей, код в комментарий приложил

Comment: @Zhihar все так же жалуется на медленность, увы

Comment: @braflovsky где вы тестируете?

Comment: @Danis учебная система, куда надо решения загружать. И все тесты невозможно увидеть, только когда что-то не проходит.

Comment: @braflovsky можете дать ссылку?

Comment: @braflovsk, значит надо реально искать O(n), потому что тут O(n^2)

Comment: @Danis так там авторизоваться надо, как студент

Comment: @Zhihar значит будем искать)

Answer (score 0):

Просто альтернативный вариант квадратичного алгоритма. Сначала за линейнок время готовим счетчики, потом для каждого интервала (start, end) за константу находим ответ. Проблема только в том, что таких интервалов надо проверить n^2.

Код на C#

```
int count(string str){
    int ret = 0;
    
    int[] acount = new int[str.Length];
    int[] bcount = new int[str.Length];
    int[] ccount = new int[str.Length];
    
    if (str[0] == 'A') acount[0] = 1;
    if (str[0] == 'B') bcount[0] = 1;
    if (str[0] == 'C') ccount[0] = 1;

    for (int i = 1; i < str.Length; i++)
    {
        acount[i] = acount[i-1];
        bcount[i] = bcount[i-1];
        ccount[i] = ccount[i-1];
        
        if (str[i] == 'A') acount[i]++;     
        if (str[i] == 'B') bcount[i]++; 
        if (str[i] == 'C') ccount[i]++; 
    }   
    
    for(int start = 0; start <str.Length-2; start ++){
        for(int end = start +2; end <str.Length; end +=3)
        {
            int a = acount[end] - (start == 0 ? 0 : acount[start-1]);
            int b = bcount[end] - (start == 0 ? 0 : bcount[start-1]);
            int c = ccount[end] - (start == 0 ? 0 : ccount[start-1]);           
            if (a == b && a == c) ret ++;
        }
    }
    
    return ret;
}
```

Проверка

```
Console.WriteLine(count("CCAABB"));
Console.WriteLine(count("CBACBA"));
Console.WriteLine(count("AAABBC"));
Console.WriteLine(count("CCBCCCABB"));
Console.WriteLine(count("CBACBACBA"));
```

Вывод

```
1
5
0
1
12
```